# iOS 8 problems with video player when "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" mode is enabled

Tags: html, ipad, video, ios8, html5-video

Since the iOS 8 was released I have been struggling  with an issue on a website I am working on.

We have made a tablet version of a website, and to get a more native app look and feel, we have enabled the apple-mobile-web-app-capable mode. Then we ask our users, first time they load the website, to add the website to the home screen.

When the website is loaded as a normal website in iOS safari browser, the videos work as they should, but in iOS 8, the video does not work in web-app-capable, when you start the web application from the home screen.

I have made a simple test setup, which reproduces the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>iOS 8 apple mobile web app capable test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test videoplayer in iOS 8 when adding shortcut to home screen">
    <meta name="author" content="TheSourceCodeAuthor">
    <head>
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="sample.mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested if it could be a cross domain issue, as our videos are loaded from another domain, then our primary domain name, but that seems not to have any influence on the issue, as I have the same issue if I host the video file on the same domain.

I have been googling for a solution for the problem, but I have been unable to find any solution.

This might be a Bug in Apple iOS 8, but I have not found any official message from Apple about this issue.

Please let me know, if you have been able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

iOS8 doesn't behave the same way with video for some reason.

I've been trying full screen video with no controls on iPad iOS8, works fine iOS6 and iOS7 but I found the only surefire way was to play then immediately pause the video out of view, then using an event listener make sure the video could begin playback and commence playing.

In my case I used the technique of using css translate to hide the video off the page to overcome the quicktime logo bug. .video-overlay is a div with the poster image of the video which gets switched upon playback.

(please excuse the mixture of jQuery and javascript event handlers!)

```
var videoWrapper = $('#video-active');
var introVideo = $('video')[0];

$(document).ready(function(){
    introVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){
        introVideo.play();
        videoWrapper.addClass('active');
        $('.video-overlay').hide();
        introVideo.removeEventListener('canplaythrough');
    });


    videoWrapper.on('timeupdate', function(event){
        onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime); //this isn't relevant - was using timeline to trigger html text over the top of video at certain points in the timeline. 
    });

    $('.video-overlay').one('click', function(){
        introVideo.play();
        introVideo.pause(); //hack to force load by playing and then immediately pausing

        videoWrapper.one('click', function(){
            introVideo.pause(); //pause video
        });
    });
});
```